# Where to look at source code of Flutter/Dart "UInt8List"

Tags: c++, flutter, dart

I am learning and exploring the source code of Flutter. I see `UInt8List` (and its friends) in `sky_engine/lib/typed_data/typed_data.dart`. However, there is only declarations (like an interface) without any implementations. I am very curious about its actual implementation, so I wonder where can I see them?

My guesses: They may be C++ code; they may have implemented the external function `external factory Uint8List(int length);`. However, after looking around the flutter Github repo I still cannot find anything related.

Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I am using Flutter (not flutter for web) thus there is no JS. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer by [@jonahwilliams](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63827):

> There is additional dart code in *_patch.dart files as part of the
> Dart SDK. For example:
>
> https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/typed_data_patch.dart
>
> This code contains native declarations like:
>
> `factory Uint8List(int length) native "TypedData_Uint8Array_new";` Which
> corresponds to a C++ code like:
> https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/6fe15f6df93150b377c306d15b1173454fda48c2/runtime/lib/typed_data.cc

And my reply (digging into more details):

> p.s. What I have found by your clues (as a remark for myself):
>
> 1. The constructor(new Uint8list) https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/6fe15f6df93150b377c306d15b1173454fda48c2/runtime/lib/typed_data.cc#L204
> 2. The actual `TypedData` https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/6fe15f6df93150b377c306d15b1173454fda48c2/runtime/vm/object.h#L9768